# When checking the cells around a single cell in a 2d array, code always returns either 1 or 0 for all cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, pygame

Using the following code:

```
import random
import pygame
mw = 165  # Matrix width
mh = 165  # Matrix height
margin = 0
newmatrix = []
finished = False

pygame.init()

matrix = []
for i in range(mw):    # This block of code just creates a new 2d array and fill it with either a 1 or a 0 in each cell
    matrix.append([])
    for j in range(mh):
         matrix[i].append(random.randint(0, 1))

def neighborchecker():    
"""This long block of code checks the 8 cells around matrix[r][c] and checks if it is a 0
    or 1, and based on that assigns that cell true or false, adding each cell up to
    see how many cells are 1s or 0s and then assigning matrix[r][c] based on its 
    neighbors"""
    for r in range(mw):
        for c in range(mh):
            try:
                if matrix[r - 1][c] == 0:
                    left = False
                else:
                    left = True
                if matrix[r - 1][c - 1] == 0:
                    botleft = False
                else:
                    botleft = True
                if matrix[r][c - 1] == 0:
                    bot = False
                else:
                    bot = True
                if matrix[r + 1][c + 1] == 0:
                    botright = False
                else:
                    botright = True
                if matrix[r + 1][c] == 0:
                    right = False
                else:
                    right = True
                if matrix[r + 1][c + 1] == 0:
                    topright = False
                else:
                    topright = True
                if matrix[r][c - 1] == 0:
                    top = False
                else:
                    top = True
                if matrix[r - 1][c + 1] == 0:
                    topleft = False
                else:
                    topleft = True
            except IndexError:
                pass
            allneighbor = sum([left, botleft, bot, botright, right, topright, top, topleft])
            if allneighbor < 2 or allneighbor > 3:
                return 0
            if allneighbor == 3:
                return 1


def createnewmatrix(): # This block creates a new matrix with new values based on what neighborchecker() returns
    for x in range(mw):
        newmatrix.append([])
        for y in range(mh):
            newmatrix[x].append(neighborchecker())
    print(newmatrix)

while not finished:
    createnewmatrix()
```

Each block of code has a comment saying what each of it does/ at least should do

What I'm expecting to get is I run this, get a matrix full of 1s and 0s, then throwing that in a loop to check each cell's neighbors and changing the corresponding cell on 'newmatrix' based on that. Then that also goes into a loop to keep updating newmatrix.

If you are familiar, I am trying to implement Conway's Game of Life in my own way and I am aware this is messy but when I run this- each cell of newmatrix- a 2d array of about 27k values is either ALL 1s or ALL 0s changing randomly when I run it, which doesnt make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

There are three main problems and a couple of things that you should fix.

- You're checking `if matrix[r - 1][c] == 0:` even when `r` is `0` (and the same goes for `c`). This means that you're checking `matrix[-1][0]`. In Python this will not give an `IndexError` as you seem to think, given you try/catch, but it will return the element in the last index. For example, if you have `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` using `a[-1]` will return `5`.
- In `createnewmatrix` you're appending constantly to `newmatrix`, but you need to reset it first to the empty state. Before the for loop you should have `newmatrix = []`, which also means...
- ...You should keep two arrays. Create the initial one randomly, create a new one based on that, and then the easiest way is to copy the new one to the initial one and repeat.

Generic things you should fix:

- There's no need to keep all those variables (`left`, `topleft`, and so on). Just keep one variable with the count and add one in case the condition is satisfied.
- You should start by initializing your matrix in a NOT random way. There are some well-known patterns in Conway's game of life. Start with one of those, so that it will last more than a few iterations.